# no appropriate default constructor available when creating constructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, constructor

I wrote a hash table class and header but I cannot construct it on main. It gives "no appropriate default constructor available". What is the cause of that?

Constructor in my header: HashTable.h

```
explicit HashTable( const HashedObj & notFound, int size = 101 );
        HashTable( const HashTable & rhs )
        : ITEM_NOT_FOUND( rhs.ITEM_NOT_FOUND ),
        array( rhs.array ), currentSize( rhs.currentSize ) { }
```

Constructor in my cpp: HashTable.cpp

```
    HashTable<HashedObj>::HashTable( const HashedObj & notFound, int size )
    : ITEM_NOT_FOUND( notFound ), array( nextPrime( size ) )
{
    makeEmpty( );
}
```

And I'm trying to do following code in my main:

```
HashTable <int> * hash = new HashTable<int>();
```

Comment: Please think of readers: don't use shouting ALL UPPERCASE IDENTIFIERS. Well, except for macros, but don't use macros either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HashTable <int> * hash = new HashTable<int>();
```

You've defined a constructor which takes argument, but here you're not passing arguments to the constructor. Instead you're using a parameterless (default) constructor which doesn't exist in your class.

Note that if you've defined a constructor (which takes argument(s)) in your class, then the compiler will not generate a default constructor for you. You've to define it yourself.

Comment: however when I try to pass any parameters, like: "= new HashTable <int>(1,3)" it gives "LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall HashTable<int>::HashTable<int>(int const &,int)" (??0?$HashTable@H@@QAE@ABHH@Z) referenced in function _main" error.

Comment: @Tugkan: Does any constructor two `int` as arguments? Why don't you see the constructor's parameter *types* and find out what the constructor can take as argument (s)?